# Open Land Cover Data for Australia

Tags: geospatial, australia, land-cover

I'm interested in both low (rough) and high (fine) resolution, open (free) and classified land cover raster data for Australia.

Ideally geodata sources; the less thematic classification is better; forest entity is the most important for my research.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WRF Preprocessing System ([WPS](http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/users/docs/user_guide_V3/users_guide_chap3.htm)) has [open land data](http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/users/download/get_sources_wps_geog.html) and a [documentation](http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/users/docs/user_guide_V3/users_guide_chap3.htm#_Land_Use_and).

You could also try the [NCAR data](http://rda.ucar.edu/datasets/ds090.0/). There is land cover included but the webpage is unclear about the data access.

A data set only covering the years between 2001 and 2012 is the [MODIS Land Cover](http://glcf.umd.edu/data/lc/). It is available as GeoTiff.

Comment: Which one should I try for Australia? Is the output a standard georeferenced raster format? Can I load it in QGIS?

Comment: These are global data sets. Please check the documentation for details. I only used the clayfrac and the sandfrac data sets some years ago. The community is large, you should find answers to your questions and several documentations.

Comment: Thank you. If there won't be any other sources, then I am going to try it. 
But I will wait with the accept, maybe others will share something processed raster geodata with a popular GIS format, like GeoTiff.

Comment: I edited my answer and added two additional data sources I know about. One is in GeoTiff but only covers the years between 2001 and 2012.

Answer (score 4):

The official Australian Land Cover can be located [**here**](http://data.gov.au/dataset/australian-land-cover-web-mercator-wms). However, it's a WMS only. You may be able to contact GeoScience Australia for a raster file.

The description:

> The Land Cover map service includes information derived from the
>   Dynamic Land Cover Dataset (2000-2008) containing Enhanced Vegetation
>   Index (EVI) information. The service provides a base-line for
>   identifying and reporting on change and trends in vegetation cover and
>   extent. It is a cached service with a Web Mercator Projection.

A preview of the WMS can be found **[here](http://data.gov.au/dataset/australian-land-cover-web-mercator-wms/resource/3a7d1521-e70e-419f-8762-d105d7f0114f)**.

In addition, there is also a land use dataset. While strictly speaking land use is not the same as land cover, they can be similar. Here is the official [**Australian Land Use dataset**](http://data.gov.au/dataset/land-use-of-australia-2010-11).  It's a raster grid which has classified land uses across the entire country.  The description:

> The Land use of Australia 2010-11 is the latest in a series of digital
>   national land use maps at national scale. Agricultural land uses and
>   their spatial distributions are based on the Australian Bureau of
>   Statistics' 2010-11 agricultural census data. The spatial distribution
>   of the agricultural land uses is modelled and was determined using
>   Advanced Very High Resolution Radiometer (AVHRR) satellite imagery
>   with training data to make agricultural land use allocations. The
>   non-agricultural land uses are drawn from existing digital maps
>   covering seven themes: topographic features, catchment scale land use,
>   protected areas, World Heritage Areas, tenure, forest type and
>   vegetation condition.

A preview of the dataset can be found [**here**](http://data.gov.au/dataset/land-use-of-australia-2010-11/resource/7a009494-0759-49e9-8e08-0d4cdae5036c).

Answer (score 3):

The AusCover data portal is also likely to be of use here. Specifically, [Land cover dynamics and phenology](http://www.auscover.org.au/dataset_categories/land-cover-dynamics-and-phenology/)